# Rails 4 + Github + Heroku: Large file storage

Tags: heroku, github, git-lfs

I have a Rails app and I perform version control with github.  My app became too large and [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) was recommended to hold my images.  Now when I push to Heroku, my files will not push.  **How do I get around this?**

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/805

Answer (score 1):

Heroku [specifically states](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code) they do not support LFS. Here's an effective workaround suggested on the [git-lfs repo](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/805):

> Try removing the `.git/hooks/pre-push` hook. However, if you keep using Git LFS, it'll re-install that hook automatically.

You could `rm` that file in a deploy script to make sure it happens automatically.